# AppDomain ExecuteAssembly of WPF app close as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, appdomain

I am launching a WPF application in a secondary AppDomain using the API "ExecuteAssembly" in a background thread.  When this secondary application is closed (e.g. user closes main window), I have found that normal shutdown sequences do not get executed as they would if the application was run within a standalone AppDomain.  Specifically, the OnExit method of the Application class is not called.

Has anyone else encountered this?

E.g. starting my secondary appdomain

```
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            var currentAppDomain = Thread.GetDomain();
            try
            {
                // line below blocks until complete
                currentAppDomain.ExecuteAssembly("PathToAssemblyToExecute");
                // at this point, executing assembly has been closed
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
                // do nothing.  this can occur due to timing issues.  framework seems
                // to send this exception out when unloading an appdomain
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // an unhandled exception has occured in this app                                        
                AppDomain.Unload(currentAppDomain);
            }
        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
```

Comment: Have you tried using System.Diagnostics.Process instead of AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly?

Comment: Yes, I gave up on AppDomains alltogether.